# Autowired object populated using ThreadLocalTargetSource does not populate for every class

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired, thread-local-storage

My Spring Boot application implements the `TenantStore` example for storing data in `ThreadLocalTargetSource` detailed in [this link](https://dzone.com/articles/an-alternative-approach-to-threadlocal-using-sprin-1)

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "destroy")
public ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTenantStore() {
    ThreadLocalTargetSource result = new ThreadLocalTargetSource();
    result.setTargetBeanName("tenantStore");
    return result;
}
```

The working example allows for the `TenantStore` object to be set and injected by the Spring Framework.  My version of the `TenantFilter` class described in that article sets the properties of the `TenantStore` object whenever a Servlet request is made

```
@Autowired
private TenantStore tenantStore;

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    try {

        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        if (authentication != null) {
            String token = (String) request.getAttribute(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALUE);

            if (token != null) {
                OAuth2AccessToken oAuth2AccessToken = tokenStore.readAccessToken(token);

                if (oAuth2AccessToken.getAdditionalInformation() != null) {
                    String tenantName = (String) oAuth2AccessToken.getAdditionalInformation().get("tenant");
                    storeTenantInThread(tenantName);
                }
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);

    } catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        clearTenant();
    }
}

private void storeTenantInThread(String tenantName) {
    tenantStore.setName(tenantName);
}

private void clearTenant() {
    tenantStore.clear();
}
```

I then have a number of services where `TenantStore` is autowired and in each of these services the `TenantStore` contains the information that was populated in the `doFilter()` method.  Except for one class.  For some reason the properties of the `TenantStore` in this class are still null.  The name of the class affected is `MyCacheService` and the architecture is as follows:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/here")
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity myGetMethod(@RequestParam("text") String text) {
        myService.myMethod(text);
        return new ResponseEntity(Http.OK);
    }

}

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private TenantStore tenantStore;

    @Autowired
    private MyOtherService myOtherService;

    public void myMethod(String text) {
        System.out.println(tenantStore.getName()); //works - prints name
        myOtherService.myOtherMethod(text);
    }

}

@Service
public class MyOtherService {

    @Autowired
    private TenantStore tenantStore;

    @Autowired
    private Map<String, MyComponent> myComponents;

    public void myOtherMethod(String text) {
        System.out.println(tenantStore.getName()); //works - prints name
        MyComponent useThisComponent = myComponents.get("componentName");
        useThisComponent.myComponentMethod(text);
    }

}

@Component("componentName")
public class MyComponent {

    @Autowired
    private TenantStore tenantStore;

    @Autowired
    private MyCacheService myCacheService;

    public void myComponentMethod(String text) {
        System.out.println(tenantStore.getName()); //works - prints name
        entityAliasCacheService.myCacheMethod(String text);
    }

}

@Service
public class MyCacheService {

    @Autowired
    private TenantStore tenantStore;

    public void myCacheMethod(String text) {
        System.out.println(tenantStore.getName()); //DOES NOT WORK - tenantStore object is not null but the name property is
    }
}
```

From what I can guess, for some reason the `TenantStore` in `MyCacheService` is being populated in a different thread, though I've no idea why.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed similar behaviour. I fixed the issue by adding a bean dependancy

```
@Service
@DependsOn("proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource") // asks Spring to first load proxy bean 
public class MyCacheService {
```

where `proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource` bean is defined like in the OP's example -

```
  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource")
  public ProxyFactoryBean proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource(ThreadLocalTargetSource threadLocalTargetSource) {
    ProxyFactoryBean result = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    result.setTargetSource(threadLocalTargetSource);
    return result;
  }
```

So, by adding the dependancy, Spring knows that it should load `MyCacheService` bean after the `proxiedThreadLocalTargetSource`. Without this dependancy, I noticed that `TenantStore` got injected instead of the proxy bean.

Comment: Same in my case, but i don't know the root cause of this needed, any idea?

Comment: @ManuelGarciadeVinuesa It is needed to give a hint to Spring that it should first load proxy bean. I believe this is needed as you see we have a in-direct dependancy on proxy bean to be initialised first. That may not be obvious for Spring to consider while resolving bean dependancy.

Comment: But in the bean creation lifecycle Spring may consider both beans, because when spring explore the "implemeted class" of the ProxyFactoryBean it might by TenantStore

`@Override
 @Nullable
 public Class<?> getTargetClass() {
  return this.targetSource.getTargetClass();
 }
`

In fact I have examples where DependsOn it is not needed for the ThreadLocalTargetSource, but I was debugging Spring and I did't get the key (too many beans and complex for debugging). So the easy way was put DependsOn.

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

Getting instance of TenantStore from org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext

First implement ApplicationContextAware like as below

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {
private static ApplicationContext context;
@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    context = applicationContext;
}
public static ApplicationContext context() {
    return context;
}
}
```

And your MyCacheService Will be like this:

```
public class MyCacheService {
public void myCacheMethod(String text) {
    TenantStore tenantStore = ApplicationContextUtil.context().getBean(TenantStore.class);
    System.out.println(tenantStore.getName());
}
}
```